# Open folder with windows explorer with specified position and size programmatically [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-explorer

I want to open specific folder with my application. Currently I'm using **ProcessInfo**, to open desired folder. The application is .net application developed in C#.

The problem is, I can't find the way to open this folder on predefined position with predefined size of the window.

I would really appreciate any suggestion that would help me deal with this matter.

Comment: You can look at this page on MSDN https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457

Answer (score 4):

To open a Windows Explorer window positioned on a particular folder you need to call it using special command line arguments

```
string path = @"D:\temp";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", "/n /e,/select," + path);
Process.Start(psi);
```

As far as I know there is no standard way (Net Framework managed code) to change the size of that window

Comment: Something from [System.Windows.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to change the size - similar to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745106(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Not an expert on WPF but it seems to be promising

Comment: It is not exactly WPF, just has WPF-like model for UI automation. I never tried to manipulate other windows' properties through it, but for finding and scrapping content in other windows it works very well.

Comment: I don't have a problem with opening folder with ProcessStartInfo. My issue is opening this folder allways on the same position (x,y) on the screen. So for example if I open two folders, I can open them one beside the other.